# ganache-cli: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: web3js, truffle, ganache-cli

This issue is simple to replicate using an Ethereum Grid (Geth) node, `ganache-cli` and `truffle`.

After starting the (light) Geth node:

**1. Fork mainnet from Geth node**

`ganache-cli --fork http://localhost:8545`

**2. Start Truffle console**

`truffle console`

**3. Build the contract (web3js)**

`abi = fs.readFileSync('./test/abi/erc20.json', 'utf-8')`

```
contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f') // Dai contract address (mainnet)
```

**4. Call on a public getter**

`contract.methods.decimals().call()`

**Error**

`Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?`

Is it possible that the Dai contract does not exist on the `ganache-cli` fork of the Geth node? How would I test for its existence?

**truffle version**

```
Truffle v5.1.15 (core: 5.1.15)
Solidity - 0.5.1 (solc-js)
Node v10.14.1
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
development: {
  host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
  port: 8546, // ganache-cli
  network_id: "*" // Any network (default: none)
}
```

**Dai Contract ABI**

```
[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"chainId_","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":true,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes4","name":"sig","type":"bytes4"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"arg1","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"arg2","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"LogNote","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_SEPARATOR","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PERMIT_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"deny","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"move","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"nonces","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"holder","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"allowed","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"permit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"pull","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"push","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"rely","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"wards","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
```

Comment: Sure the connection is well established? Like, does web3.eth.getBlockNumber returns expected?

Comment: Yikes: `web3.eth.getBlockNumber() // 82`

Comment: The contract at `0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f` does not implement function `decimals()`

Comment: @goodvibration it's a public storage variable so it should create its own getter function right?

Comment: Yes, but this means that your contract implements this getter, not that the contract deployed at that address does.

Answer (score 0):

With `contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, addr)`,

The one and only reason for `contract.methods.decimals().call()` to throw:

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
```

Is if no contract which implements function `decimals()` is deployed at `addr`.

Comment: It transpired that João Quintanilha was correct in the comments, it was an issue in the Geth node not syncing to the latest block. The contract did not exist according to Geth and so this error was thrown. `contract.methods.decimals().call()` does now return `18` which is the value of the public storage variable `decimals`.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, I have slightly updated the answer (the last line).